# How to get information from Django_tables2 row?

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I have declared a table and want to fetch the row's value which is checked using checkboxfield. Any help, how can i write this event in my views so that everytime I select a row and hit submit button, it returns the row's values.Code goes like this:

```
    class mytables(tables.Table):
          new_database = tables.CheckBoxColumn()
          student =tables.Column(accessor='Student')
          Class = tables.Column(accessor='class')
```

And in my templates a submit button.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to choose a suitable value for the `CheckBoxColumn`. Generally if you're displaying a queryset, you'll use the `pk` of each object for the `CheckBoxColumn`. In your case this would look like:

```
class EnrollmentTable(tables.Table):
    selection = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='pk')
    student = tables.Column()
    class = tables.Column()
```

Then you'll need to render the table within a form, so that the user can submit the form, e.g.:

```
<form action="/someurl/" method="post">
    {% load render_tables from django_tables2 %}
    {% render_table table %}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then you'll need a view hooked up to `/someurl/`. In your case the view will need to look at the `POST` variable `selection`:

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pks = request.POST.getlist("selection")
        selected_objects = SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
        # do something with selected_objects
    else:
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but While debugging I see that pks is a list containing only None as in if i select two rows then [u'None,u'None]...any thoughts about that?

Comment: That sounds like you're not using saved model objects as your table data.

Comment: Thanks a lot i forgot to include the pk value in queryset. Its working fine.

Comment: Fantastic answer. It seems strange that this isn't included in the official  documentation