# Using "record" in attributes Django Tables 2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm moving my tables to django-tables2. By now is almost everything working ok, but now I have a problem.

In my current version i use checkboxes to select items

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_delete" name="event" id="event.id"
                                               value="{{ event.id }}" />
```

this way in the view i can recover the event.id using `request.POST.getlist('event')`

Now I'm trying to add the "value" attribute to a CheckBoxColumn

```
select = tables.CheckBoxColumn(attrs={'td__input': {'class': 'checkbox_delete', 'name': 'event', **'value': [A('id')]**}, 'th__input': {'id': 'selectAll'}},
                                   empty_values=())
```

I've been playing with the Accesor and the record.id which I use in a templateColumn.

How can I pass the id to the value attribute??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution here [How to get information from Django_tables2 row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850316/how-to-get-information-from-django-tables2-row/10860711#10860711)

Just need to define `select = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='pk')`  and it add the value as the record.id

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like this:

`id = tables.CheckBoxColumn()`

This way, the column will be rendered like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="X">
```

where X will be the value of the id field.

Now for a more complete answer:

You can add `td__input` to override some defaults *but* I don't believe what you can set it to *different* values for each column ! By checking the source:

https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns/checkboxcolumn.py

you will see that in the `render` method in `CheckBoxColumn` will create an AttributeDict containing the attributes from input, td__input  and some defaults, like this:

```
def render(self, value, bound_column):  # pylint: disable=W0221
        default = {
            'type': 'checkbox',
            'name': bound_column.name,
            'value': value
        }
        general = self.attrs.get('input')
        specific = self.attrs.get('td__input')
        attrs = AttributeDict(default, **(specific or general or {}))
        return mark_safe('' % attrs.as_html())
```

So the attrs you define will be the same in all columns since attrs.as_html will just convert the 'x':'y' dict entries to x=y...

So if you want to have total control and do whatever you like with the values for each column, just subclss `CheckBoxColumn` and override `render` (left as an excersise to the reader).

**Update**

Also, a very nice thing about your own `render` method is that you don't need to define the *same* parameters as the base one. This is because django-tables2 uses the getargspec function to find out which arguments your render expects and pass them to the `render` method. So, if you take a look at the https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/rows.py you will see that the available parameters that can be passed to `render`, along with their values are:

```
available = {
      'value':        value,
      'record':       self.record,
      'column':       bound_column.column,
      'bound_column': bound_column,
      'bound_row':    self,
      'table':        self._table,
}
```

So, for instance you can define your `render` method like:

`def render(self, value, bound_column, record):`

to also pass the record to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it that way

Comment: thanks. I want to disable checkboxes based on the contents of the row, and this seems like a good way to do it. The signature of the parent class render has changed to def render(self, value, bound_column, record) but it in no way affects this solution